# Shell_NotifyIcon producing multiple icons

Tags: winapi, swt, windows-shell

We are using SWT (java based) in our application to contribute to Windows notification area.

By moving to Windows 10 we see the display of icons are increasing as time passes eventually filling up the whole the notification area.

I checked internal SWT code and below is the code how SWT calls  Shell_NotifyIconW to contribute icons.

```
NOTIFYICONDATA iconData = OS.IsUnicode ? (NOTIFYICONDATA) new NOTIFYICONDATAW () : new NOTIFYICONDATAA ();
    iconData.cbSize = NOTIFYICONDATA.sizeof;
    iconData.uID = id;
    iconData.hWnd = display.hwndMessage;
    iconData.hIcon = hIcon;
    iconData.uFlags = OS.NIF_ICON;
    OS.Shell_NotifyIcon (OS.NIM_MODIFY, iconData);
```

Code in the OS.Shell_NotifyIcon method

```
public static final boolean Shell_NotifyIcon (int dwMessage, NOTIFYICONDATA lpData) {
    if (IsUnicode) return Shell_NotifyIconW (dwMessage, (NOTIFYICONDATAW)lpData);
    return Shell_NotifyIconA (dwMessage, (NOTIFYICONDATAA)lpData);
}
```

So whenever we call SWT method for setting image/icon in the notification area. Multiple tray icons are created.

In our application we only initialize the tray item with OS.NIM_ADD once and then keep setting the images of tray item continuously which internally calls OS.NIM_MODIFY as shown above.

Does anyone have any hints on this issue ?

How can i see internal Windows shell SDK logs/traces ? How can i see who is creating the icons ?

**UPDATE1**

This issue is also reproducible when the scale factor of your computer is changed

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: You should make a [mcve]. If you want us to look at code. Or you could debug this yourself. Log all calls to `Shell_NotifyIcon`. Then it should be obvious where you are going wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your reply...another problem i am not able to reproduce this problem on my system...my users can reproduce this

Comment: Add logging code. Get users to run program then send logging output.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update.

This issue is current under investigation by the SWT team

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488739